Trying to Find the Maximum and Minimum values from a range set by cells containg specific value
I need to extract data from Input sheet to another sheet as shown below
Input sheet:



ColumnF
ColumnV




2
120


2
100


2
130


2
150


-1
70


-1
200


-1
150


-1
60



To new sheet to extract from Input



ColumnA
ColumnB
ColumnC




2
150
100


-1
200
60



So I have written the following VBA Code. I getting run time error '1004'
Unable to get the Match property of the worksheetfunction class in the highlighted line. And first part of the code is also slow.
Sub ExtractGeotechForces()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim sourceColumn As Range
    Dim uniqueValues As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set your source and destination worksheets
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws2.Name = "ForceExtract"
    
    ' Define the source column range
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set sourceColumn = ws1.Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
    
    ' Create a dictionary to store unique values
    Set uniqueValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the source column
    For Each cell In sourceColumn
        If Not uniqueValues.exists(cell.Value) Then
            uniqueValues.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Transfer unique values to the destination sheet
    ws2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Elevation"
    i = 2
    For Each Item In uniqueValues.keys
        ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Item
        i = i + 1
    Next Item
    
    ' Optionally, you can sort the list alphabetically
    ws2.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws2.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws2.Range("A2:A" & uniqueValues.Count), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws2.Sort
        .SetRange ws2.Range("A2:A" & uniqueValues.Count)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
'finding first and last row of elevation
        Dim ElevToFind As Long
        Dim ElevCount As Long
        Dim ElevfirstRow As Long
        Dim ElevlastRow As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim maxValue As Double
        Dim minValue As Double
        Dim ElevRange As Range
        
        Set ElevRange = ws1.Range("F:F")
        
        'Total Elev count
        ElevCount = ws2.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To ElevCount
        ' Get the elvation to search
        ElevToFind = ws2.Cells(j, 1).Value
        ' Find the first row with elevation Error Line
        ***ElevfirstRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ElevToFind,ElevRange, 0)*** 
        length = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ElevRange, ElevToFind)
        ElevlastRow = ElevfirstRow + length - 1
'Find Max & Min M11 of the Elevation
        Dim M11startCell, M11endCell, M11Range As Range
        Dim M11max, M11min As Double
        Set M11startCell = ws1.Cells(ElevfirstRow, 21)
        Set M11endCell = ws1.Cells(ElevlastRow, 21)
        Set M11Range = ws1.Range(M11startCell, M11endCell)
        M11max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(M11Range)
        M11min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(M11Range)
        ws2.Cells(j, 2).Value = maxValue
        ws2.Cells(j, 3).Value = minValue
    Next j
    
    MsgBox "Forces extracted successfully!"
        
        
 End Sub   

Modified Code as per @FaneDuru code
Option Explicit
 
 Sub ExtractGeotechForces2()
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, arrFin, arrIt
  Dim i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
  Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws2.Name = "ForceExtract"
  
  ' Place the source column and item values in an array, for faster processing:
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = ws1.Range("F2:AD" & lastRow).Value2
    
    'load the dictionary (unique keys and all their values):
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 11), arr(i, 14), arr(i, 17), arr(i, 20), arr(i, 23))
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1)) 'place the item in an array to modify it
            ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1) 'increase the array no of elements preserving existing
            arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 11), arr(i, 14), arr(i, 17), arr(i, 20), arr(i, 23))  'place the value from B:B as the last array element
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt 'place back the updated array
        End If
    Next i
    
    'ReDim the necessary final array:
    ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 8)
    Dim MaxVal As Single, MinVal As Single
    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        arrFin(i + 1, 1) = dict.keys()(i) 'place the dictionary key
        arrFin(i + 1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Max(dict.Items()(i)) 'Max
        arrFin(i + 1, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Min(dict.Items()(i)) 'Min
    Next i
    'drop the processed array at once:
    ws2.Range("A1").Resize(, 3).Value = Array("ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC") 'Columns headers
    ws2.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin  'Processed values
End Sub

I have modified the code to add more data from more columns (8) to dictionary need help to extarct the min and max of each columns to new sheet

Not sure I can understand what you try doing (only looking to your code and question...). What do you mean by ColumnA and ColumnA? Aren't they the real columns A:A and B:B? Should they be F:F and G:G?  If not why do you use Set sourceColumn = ws1.Range("F2:F" & lastRow) and extract unique keys from this column?

"It is not working" is not helpful at all. What does it do? Crashes Excel? Crashes computer? Wrong Answer? error message?  If error message, what is it and what line throws it? Be sure to put Option Explicit at the start of your module to catch typos, undeclared variables, etc.

A pivot Table would make this in seconds and easy to maintain updated. Just in case you wanna check it out.

Sorry Guys, I am new to this forum, I am alos not that much expert in VBA or programming,   As @FaneDuru Mention column A is indicaive only I will try to be more specific next time.                                                                                                                 And @ Ron Rosenfeld, I have changed my code and I will attach snip of error and line as u mentioned. Also done Option Explicit

Please, try the next VBA solution:
Sub ExtractGeotechForces()
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, arrFin, arrIt
  Dim i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
  Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws2.name = "ForceExtract"
  
  ' Place the source column and item values in an array, for faster processing:
    lastRow = ws1.cells(ws1.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
    arr = ws1.Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value2 ' place the range in an array for faster processing
    
    'load the dictionary (unique keys and all their values):
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate the array by rows
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then 'if the key does  not exist>
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2)) 'create it and place as item an array with arr(i, 2) value
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1)) 'place the item in an array to modify it
            ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1) 'increase the array no of elements preserving existing
            arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = arr(i, 2)        'place the value from B:B as the last array element
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt 'place back the updated array
        End If
    Next i
    
    'ReDim the necessary final array:
    ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To 3)

    Dim MaxVal As Single, MinVal As Single
    For i = 0 To dict.count - 1 'iterate between the dictionary elements (zero based)
        arrFin(i + 1, 1) = dict.keys()(i) 'place the dictionary key
        arrFin(i + 1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Max(dict.Items()(i)) 'Max
        arrFin(i + 1, 3) = WorksheetFunction.min(dict.Items()(i)) 'Min
    Next i
    'drop the processed array at once:
    ws2.Range("A1").Resize(, 3).value = Array("ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC") 'Columns headers
    ws2.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin  'Processed values
End Sub


Thank you @FaneDuru  It works like magic, I will check into the commands you have provided, If possible can you please brife what command does which function

@Hasan I thought I did it... I commented the code lines I considered that they may not be clear enough. I will edit the answer and place more comments. If something unclear, please specify where specifically you could not understand what the code tries doing.

@Hasan I think, now all code lines which could be problematic in terms of understanding are well commented. If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Hi @FaneDuru want to add more column B (i.e more like some 8 column data and assign to key variable) and extract max and min values of each column (so 16 columns in output). I have modified the directory part I am not sure about the final array. Can you please help.

@Hasan Always it is good to ask specifically, according to your need. The answer is Yes, it can be adapted. Instead of an array a dictionary item, you should use a jagged array (an array of arrays) each array in the jagged array keeping the records for one column. Now I am driving, anyhow...

Oh thats new to me, Let my check jagged array

You can place another question, using my above code and ask for exrending it to cover 16 columns. I will be at home after about an hour. But in the meantime somebody else may answer it...

@Hasan Please, post here the link to the new question. I will be at home in about half an hour. If not somebody else answered the question I will prepare an answer.

Hai @FaneDuru Sorry for posting late https://stackoverflow.com/q/78375603/24602387 here is the link as requested

@Hasan I almost finished the solution yesterday night. I will finish it in some minutes and post the answer if somebody else did not place a better answer...

@Hasan Already posted it. Of course, using a similar logic, a constant to keep the needed number of columns, a dictionary and a jagged array. I must confess i did not read your question, supposing that I know the theme. I hope it does not contain other requirements or approach modifications. If so, I will be able to look at it after some other hours. I will leave home in some minutes...

Your VBA is going to a lot of trouble to just replicate the UNIQUE, MAXIFS and MINIFS excel functions.
Assuming no version constraints as per your tags, you can do this using a single Excel formula:

Create a Table from your data and Name it InputTbl
Then use this formula in some cell:

=LET(
    hdrs, {"ColumnA", "Max", "Min"},
    colA, UNIQUE(InputTbl[ColumnA]),
    ma, BYROW(
        colA,
        LAMBDA(arr, MAXIFS(InputTbl[ColumnB], InputTbl[ColumnA], arr))
    ),
    mi, BYROW(
        colA,
        LAMBDA(arr, MINIFS(InputTbl[ColumnB], InputTbl[ColumnA], arr))
    ),
    VSTACK(hdrs, HSTACK(colA, ma, mi))
)

Input

Output

Edit*With updated keys showing Excel 2007, the following VBA should do what you want:
Option Explicit
Sub ExtractGeotechForces()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim sourceColumn As Range
    Dim uniqueValues As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Item
    
    ' Set your source and destination worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input sheet") 'ActiveSheet is bad practice
    
    ' need error checking to ensure this worksheet does not already exist
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ForceExtract").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws2.Name = "ForceExtract"
    
    ' Define the source column range
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set sourceColumn = ws1.Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
    
    ' Create a dictionary to store unique values
    Set uniqueValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the source column
    For Each cell In sourceColumn
        If Not uniqueValues.exists(cell.Value) Then
            uniqueValues.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Transfer unique values to the destination sheet
    ws2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Elevation"
    i = 2
    For Each Item In uniqueValues.keys
        ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Item
        i = i + 1
    Next Item
    
'Create array for results
'use "0" for headers Max and Min
  Dim resultsArray As Variant
  Dim K As Long
ReDim resultsArray(0 To uniqueValues.Count, 1 To 2)
resultsArray(0, 1) = "Max"
resultsArray(0, 2) = "Min"

'Get Max in Min for each uniquevalue
    i = 0
    For Each Item In uniqueValues.keys
    i = i + 1
    resultsArray(i, 2) = 9.9E+305
    With sourceColumn
        For K = 1 To .Cells.Count
            If .Cells(K, 1) = Item Then
                resultsArray(i, 1) = IIf(resultsArray(i, 1) > .Cells(K, 2), resultsArray(i, 1), .Cells(K, 2))
                resultsArray(i, 2) = IIf(resultsArray(i, 2) < .Cells(K, 2), resultsArray(i, 2), .Cells(K, 2))
            End If
        Next K
    End With
    Next Item
    
'write results
With ws2.Cells(1, 2).Resize(rowsize:=UBound(resultsArray, 1) + 1, columnsize:=2)
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = resultsArray
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
    

    MsgBox "Forces extracted successfully!"
    
End Sub



I need VBA for excel version 2019 and lower.

@Hasan Then please specify the lowest version you need in your keys so others won't waste time.

Yah I have updated my post

@Hasan VBA solution added

Unique Maximums and Minimums
Sub ExtractGeotechForces()
    
    ' Constants
    
    Const SRC_TOP_KEY_CELL As String = "F2"
    Const SRC_VALUE_COLUMN As String = "V"
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "ForceExtract"
    Const DST_TOP_LEFT_CELL As String = "A1"
    Dim dHeaders() As Variant: dHeaders = VBA.Array("Type", "Max", "Min")
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim skrg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_TOP_KEY_CELL)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set skrg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = skrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_VALUE_COLUMN)
    
    Dim skData() As Variant, svData() As Variant
    
    If srCount = 1 Then
        ReDim skData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): skData(1, 1) = skrg.Value
        ReDim svData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): svData(1, 1) = svrg.Value
    Else
        skData = skrg.Value
        svData = svrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Unique
    
    Dim dictMax As Object: Set dictMax = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictMax.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim dictMin As Object: Set dictMin = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictMin.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Value As Variant, sr As Long, skStr As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        skStr = CStr(skData(sr, 1))
        Value = svData(sr, 1)
        If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then
            If Not dictMax.Exists(skStr) Then
                dictMax(skStr) = Value
                dictMin(skStr) = Value
            Else
                If Value > dictMax(skStr) Then
                    dictMax(skStr) = Value
                ElseIf Value < dictMin(skStr) Then
                    dictMin(skStr) = Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Destination Array
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dictMax.Count + 1
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(dHeaders) + 1
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For dc = 1 To dcCount
        dData(1, dc) = dHeaders(dc - 1)
    Next dc
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1
    
    For Each Value In dictMax.Keys
        dr = dr + 1
        dData(dr, 1) = Value
        dData(dr, 2) = dictMax(Value)
        dData(dr, 3) = dictMin(Value)
    Next Value
    
    ' Destination Range
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dsh As Object:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dsh = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim dCodeName As String
    
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        dCodeName = dsh.CodeName
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dsh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = dwb.Sheets.Add(After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count))
    dws.Name = DST_SHEET_NAME
    
    If Len(dCodeName) > 0 Then
        dwb.VBProject.VBComponents(dws.CodeName).Name = dCodeName
    End If
    
    With dws.Range(DST_TOP_LEFT_CELL).Resize(, dcCount)
        .Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        ' Format.
        '.Font.Bold = True
        '.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Forces extracted successfully.", vbInformation
        
End Sub

