Find the Maximum and Minimum values from a range set by cells containg specific value by VBA Array function
I need to extract data from Input sheet to another sheet as shown below
Input sheet:

I have added the image of the source file from which i want to extract the data
And I have hidden someww columns so that only columns from which i want to extract data are vissible
As seen from the Image Column F of solurce file has many duplicate values say 10 no of rows with value 2 but have different values in the other columns in the coresponding rows.
I want to group the other column data say (G J M P S V Y AB) to a single key value on column F say 2 and find the maximum & Minimum of each columns and extract the same to new sheet as

I have modifed some code which got help from this forum for extract similar data for just 2 columns as below
Sub ExtractGeotechForces3()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim arr, arrFin(), arrIt
    Dim i As Long, dict As Object
    
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws2.Name = "ForceExtract"
    
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = ws1.Range("F2:AD" & lastRow).Value2
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 11), arr(i, 14), arr(i, 17), arr(i, 20), arr(i, 23))
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1))
            ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1)
            arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 11), arr(i, 14), arr(i, 17), arr(i, 20), arr(i, 23))
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Adjust the size of arrFin to accommodate additional columns
    ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 15) ' 1 for elevation, 7 for max, and 7 for min
    
    Dim key As Variant, values As Variant
    For i = 1 To dict.Count
        key = dict.keys()(i - 1)
        values = dict(key)
        arrFin(i, 1) = key ' Place the key in the output array
        
        ' Loop through the values array to extract max and min for each column
        Dim j As Long, k As Long
        For j = 0 To UBound(values)
            ' Calculate maximum and minimum values for each column
            For k = 1 To 7
                arrFin(i, k * 2) = WorksheetFunction.Max(values(j)) ' Max value
                arrFin(i, k * 2 + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Min(values(j)) ' Min value
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Output the results to the destination worksheet
    ws2.Range("A1").Resize(, 15).Value = Array("Elevation", "N1-Max", "N1-Min", "N2-Max", "N2-Min", "Q12-Max", "Q12-Min", "Q23-Max", "Q23-Min", "Q13-Max", "Q13-Min", "M11-Max", "M11-Min", "M22-Max", "M22-Min", "M13-Max", "M13-Min") ' Column headers
    ws2.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin ' Processed values
End Sub

Now I want to extend it to multiple columns but when i try to run the programm the maximum and minimum values of same column repeates for all extracted column


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator  It's no way to know where is Column F on your screenshot.

Please, try the next adapted answer. It uses a constant able to keep the number of desired columns to be processed, being dynamic, from this point of view. It uses a jagged array, as I said in a comment to the other question. It works for consecutive columns, starting from "A:A".
Edited
Adapted the code to work with discontinuous columns range. Only adapted a code line and inserted to new code lines, able to extract the necessary columns in the same array, now containing only the necessary columns:
Sub ExtractGeotechForces_8Cols()
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, arrFin, arrIt(), arr1(), arrJG
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, dict As Object, lastColLetter As String
  Const retCols As Long = 8 'use here the number of columns to be processed (except the type)
  
  Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
  Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ws2.name = "ForceExtract"
  
  ' Place the source column and item values in an array, for faster processing:
    lastRow = ws1.cells(ws1.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'last row of A:A column
     
    'MODIFIED________________________________________________________________________________
    lastColLetter = "P"  'You need to place here the letter of the last column!!!  - MODIFIED!
    'END MODIFIED____________________________________________________________________________

    arr = ws1.Range("A2:" & lastColLetter & lastRow).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
    
    'CODE ADDED________________________________________________________________________________________________
    Dim arrCols(): arrCols = Array(1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16) 'Array to keep the RELATIVE indexes
                                                                 'of the necessary columns. In my testing
                                                                 'environment I used range "A2:P" & lastR
                                                                 'and columns A,C,F,G,H,I,L,M,P
    'For initial range "F:U", using the same index coresponds to columns F,H,K,L,M,N,Q,R,U!
    If UBound(arrCols) <> retCols Then MsgBox "You did not choose an appropriate number of column indexes...": Exit Sub
    'recreate arr array to contain only consecutive columns, the one specified in the above array:
    arr = Application.index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), arrCols)
    'END CODE ADDED______________________________________________________________________________________

    'load the dictionary (unique keys and all their values):
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary
    ReDim arrJG(retCols - 1) 'ReDim the Jagged arrays (array of arrays...)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the arr rows:
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            For j = 0 To retCols - 1
                arrJG(j) = Array(arr(i, j + 2)) 'build the jagged array for each type
            Next j
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), arrJG           'add the jagged array as item
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1))  'place the item in an array to process/modify it
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt) 'iterate between arrIt elements
               arr1 = arrIt(j) 'without that, VBA does  not understand that arrIt(j) is an array...
               ReDim Preserve arr1(UBound(arr1) + 1) 'add an element to the array, preserving existing values
               arr1(UBound(arr1)) = arr(i, j + 2)    'place the arr corresponding value in the last array element
               arrIt(j) = arr1      'place back processed arr1 in arrIt array
            Next j
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt 'place back the updated arrIt array as item
        End If
    Next i
    
    'ReDim the necessary final array:
    ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To retCols * 2 + 1) 'the number of columns is calculated using retCols
    Dim MaxVal As Single, MinVal As Single              'declare the variables to also accept decimals
    For i = 0 To dict.count - 1                         'iterate between the dictionary elements:
        arrFin(i + 1, 1) = dict.keys()(i) 'place the dictionary key in the first array column
        k = 0                             'reinitialize the variable keeping the unique pairs (Max - Min) columns
        For j = 0 To retCols - 1 ' iterate between the number of columns (except the "Type" one)
          arrFin(i + 1, k + 2) = WorksheetFunction.Max(dict.Items()(i)(j)) 'Max
          arrFin(i + 1, k + 3) = WorksheetFunction.min(dict.Items()(i)(j)) 'Min
          k = k + 2
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'Build the columns headers:
    Dim arrH: ReDim arrH(1 To 1, 1 To retCols * 2 + 1)
    k = 1 'reinitialize this variable to keep the number of Max/Min pairs
    arrH(1, 1) = "Type" 'load first array header element
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrH, 2) 'Build headers for Min and Max
        arrH(1, i) = "Max" & k: arrH(1, i + 1) = "Min" & k
        i = i + 1: k = k + 1 'to iterate from two to two and increment the pair Max/Min variable
    Next i
    'drop the headers array content in the first row:
    ws2.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrH, 2)).value = arrH 'Columns headers
    
    'drop the processed array starting from the second row, at once:
    ws2.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin  'Processed values
End Sub


@Hasan The logic of my code involves consecutive columns... So I understood from your previous question. This allowed creating the array dynamically, to be used for as many columns as you need. The single adaptation you must do is to use an array containing all columns and use only the 8 columns you need when extract data... I need to leave home now...

Hai @FaneDuru When I try to run with another sheet I am getting Runtime error 1004:Unable to get the max property of work sheet @ arrFin(i + 1, k + 2) = WorksheetFunction.Max(dict.Items()(i)(j)) 'Max line , Can you please help

@Hasan What do you mean by "to run with another sheet"? Did you arrange the columns consecutively, starting from the first column? I have an idea to adapt the above code only using a new array variable (containing the relative column index in the range) and a way to recreate the initial array to keep only the necessary columns... I will start working in about 10 minutes...

@Hasan Please, look to the above code and try understanding what the new array (arrCols) must contain (the relative indexes of the columns to be use). Then, test it. If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications... If you want me to test it on your workbook, if not something confidential, try sending it to mai personal mail (from my user profile...). But the best idea would be to try adapting it by yourself and understand what and how the code does/works. Only in this way you will learn more, I think.

Thank you @FaneDuru I have figured out, Thank you It was help full

Your code is close to finish.

The first item in Dict should be added with Array(Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 8)...)).
The data is added to the dictionary by row. Your objective is to find the maximum or minimum value in a column. So adding a For loop to extract arrCol.

Option Explicit
Sub ExtractGeotechForces3()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim arr, arrFin(), arrIt
    Dim i As Long, dict As Object
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws2 = Sheets("ForceExtract")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws2 Is Nothing Then
        Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ws2.Name = "ForceExtract"
    Else
        ws2.Cells.Clear
    End If
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = ws1.Range("F2:AE" & lastRow).Value2
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 11), arr(i, 14), arr(i, 17), arr(i, 20), arr(i, 23), arr(i, 26)))
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1))
            ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1)
            arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 11), arr(i, 14), arr(i, 17), arr(i, 20), arr(i, 23), arr(i, 26))
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt
        End If
    Next i
    ' Adjust the size of arrFin to accommodate additional columns
    ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 17)  ' 1 for elevation, 7 for max, and 7 for min
    Dim key As Variant, values As Variant, arrCol, iCnt As Long
    For i = 1 To dict.Count
        key = dict.keys()(i - 1)
        values = dict(key)
        iCnt = UBound(values) + 1
        ReDim arrCol(1 To iCnt)
        arrFin(i, 1) = key ' Place the key in the output array
        ' Loop through the values array to extract max and min for each column
        Dim j As Long, k As Long, s As Long
        For j = 0 To UBound(values)
            ' Calculate maximum and minimum values for each column
            For k = 1 To 8
                For s = 1 To iCnt
                    arrCol(s) = values(s - 1)(k - 1)
                Next
                arrFin(i, k * 2) = WorksheetFunction.Max(arrCol) ' Max value
                arrFin(i, k * 2 + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Min(arrCol) ' Min value
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Output the results to the destination worksheet
    ws2.Range("A1").Resize(, 17).Value = Array("Elevation", "N1-Max", "N1-Min", "N2-Max", "N2-Min", "Q12-Max", "Q12-Min", "Q23-Max", "Q23-Min", "Q13-Max", "Q13-Min", "M11-Max", "M11-Min", "M22-Max", "M22-Min", "M13-Max", "M13-Min") ' Column headers
    ws2.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin ' Processed values
End Sub



Hai @taller  Thanks for your help but the last row M13 Max and M13 Min are missing while extracting, can you please help me

AE is missing in OP (other column data say (G J M P S V Y AB) ).  "M13-Max", "M13-Min" is on the header of output table, but M_12 [kN m is used on source table. I've update the code to catch the last col.

You could achieve this by formula as well - maybe, with a lot of data, slow ...
=LET(zData,A2:A9,dataAll,B1:D9,
data,DROP(dataAll,1),dataHeader,CHOOSEROWS(dataAll,1),
uniqueZ,UNIQUE(zData),
λMaxMin,LAMBDA(z,col,MaxMin,LET(df,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data,col),zData=z),IF(MaxMin=1,MAX(df),MIN(df)))),
minMaxValues,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(uniqueZ),COLUMNS(data)*2,LAMBDA(r,c,λMaxMin(INDEX(uniqueZ,r),INT((c+1)/2),--ISODD(c)))),
minMaxHeader,MAKEARRAY(1,COLUMNS(data)*2,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(dataHeader,r,INT(c+1)/2) & " " & CHOOSE(--ISODD(c)+1,"Min","Max"))),
VSTACK(HSTACK("Elevation",minMaxHeader),HSTACK(uniqueZ,minMaxValues)))


